# Has many through with pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

A `Venue` hasMany `Subscription`

A `Subscription` belongsToMany `User`

How can I retrieve all `User` from `Venue` through `Subscription`?

I imagine something like:

```
$venue->subscribers // Return all `User`
```

My database scheme: http://www.laravelsd.com/share/AAjuYS

### I have tried

```
class Venue {
    public function subscribers() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Subscription');
    }
}
```

Fails with error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.subscription_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `subscriptions`.`venue_id` from `users` inner join `subscriptions` on `subscriptions`.`id` = `users`.`subscription_id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `subscriptions`.`venue_id` = 1)
```

Comment: hasManyThrough work with 3 tables i think maybe you should go with raw sql

Comment: Your link does not allow me to look at your schema.

Comment: Sorry: http://www.laravelsd.com/share/AAjuYS

Answer (score -1):

```
// In Venue class
public function subscribers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Subscription');
}
```

You can read about it in the documentation, it's pretty straight-forward: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#Has-Many-Through

Comment: Throws error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.subscription_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `subscriptions`.`venue_id` from `users` inner join `subscriptions` on `subscriptions`.`id` = `users`.`subscription_id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `subscriptions`.`venue_id` = 1)`

Comment: Your database schema does not contain any relations between the different tables. If you follow the conventions described in the Laravel documentation (That I linked), the code I provided you will work.

Comment: In case you didn't figure this out yet: You need to add relations in the database. You need a pivot-table for Venue and Subscription, and a subscription_id field in your User table